# What's the equivalent of .NET's String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace in C++?

Tags: c++

I know this is a very easy thing to check for manually, but is there an out-of-the-box recommended way in C++ for checking whether a std::string is either empty or contains only whitespace characters?

If the standard library doesn't have this, is there any other library that does?

Comment: By string do you mean `char *`, `std::string`, or `std::string *`?

Comment: I meant std::string. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer:

```
bool
isNullOrWhiteSpace( std::string const& str )
{
    return std::find_if(
            str.begin(),
            str.end(),
            []( unsigned char ch ) { return !isspace( ch ); } )
        == str.end();
}
```

But it's probably not very useful; it depends on the global
locale, and won't handle some of the most frequent encodings
(like UTF-8).

Comment: One could use `std::isspace` that takes a locale argument to not depend on the global locale, but encoding is indeed an issue.

Comment: @CoryNelson It's not that difficult, but it does introduce additional issues which distract from the immediate answer to the question.  If you're doing any text processing at all, at least in C++03 (without lambda), you'll create the appropriate functional object types, and put them in your toolbox.  For that matter, even with lambda, you might do this, using `IsSpace()` (or `IsSpace( desiredLocale )` instead of the lambda.

Comment: This code doesn't compile with VS 2011: `error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const char' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 3186`

Comment: @JamesKanze Now it compiles correctly, thanks. Can you please also add a small bug fix to negate the return value in the predicate: `return !isspace( ch );`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a standard one but it's fairly easy to write

```
bool isNullOrWhiteSpace(const char* c) {
   if (!c) { 
     return true;
   }
   while (*c) {
     if (!isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*c))) {
       return false;
     }
     c++;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: That's NullOrEmpty, not NullOrWhiteSpace?

Comment: @tabstop must finish coffee before answering, fixed

Comment: @JamesKanze care to be more specific?

Comment: `isspace(*c)` is undefined behavior, at least according to the C and the C++ standards.  You cannot pass a `char` to the one argument version of `isspace`.  (The code is also unnecessarily complicated, with tests for special cases which aren't, and returns all over the place.)

Comment: Undefined behaviour if `char` is signed and any has a negative value (thus out of range for `isspace`).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In this case, yes.  It can result in a value of the `int` which isn't in the proscribed range of `isspace` (`[0,UCHAR_MAX]`).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Okay, so it's not passing a `char`, but failing to specify preconditions, which is the problem. In short I prefer Mike's description of that issue, but I do agree with your parenthetical as presented.

Comment: @JamesKanze how is your solution getting around this problem then?  I would expect the iteration of `std::string` in `find` to also return `char` values

Comment: @JaredPar: The parameter type of his lambda causes a conversion to unsigned char.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley but how is this done *safely*.  Is the conversion from `char` -> `unsigned char` inherently safe here?  If so it seems the undefined behavior in my solution can be fixed with a `static_cast`

Comment: @JaredPar The undefined behavior can be fixed with a `static_cast`; this is, after all, what we regularly did back in the days of C (except that it was a C style cast, of course).  (Of course, your code doesn't answer the original question, which asked about strings in C++.)